# Flask-SocketIO not recieving messages from front end when used with RabbitMQ

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I'm trying to setup my Flask app to use RabbitMQ as a message queue. It works fine if I emit messages from the server but if I try to emit messages nothing happens. It seems like the front end socket is not communicating with the queue.

My socket code looks as follows:

```
from flask_socketio import emit, SocketIO

socketio_mp = SocketIO(message_queue='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//')

@socketio_mp.on('connected', namespace='/test')
def joined():
    """Sent by clients when they enter a room.
    A status message is broadcast to all people in the room."""
    print('connected')
```

The socket is initialized correctly as shown in the Flask-SocketIO docs. The `connected` event is never triggered even though it is emitted from the front end.

```
var namespace = "/test";
socket = io.connect(location.protocol + "//" + document.domain + ":" + location.port + namespace);

socket.on("connect", function() {

    console.log("connected");
    socket.emit("connected", {msg: "next"});
});
```

I also get no errors in the console.

Comment: The provided code does not show how you're running the app. As stated on the Flask-SocketIO docs, you should run the app via `socketio.run()` wrapping the Flask `app.run()`.

Comment: @farzad I actually do initialize the app the right way. The app works when the message queue is not added.

Comment: The issue address here https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your `SocketIO` instance, you have to pass your Flask app as a first argument:

```
socketio_mp = SocketIO(app, message_queue='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//')
```

As a side note, I'm not sure what you expect to be different when you add a message queue in this way. The clients never talk to the message queue. The queue is used internal when you have multiple Flask-SocketIO servers or emit-only processes. Clients do not have direct access to the queue.

Comment: I'm using a blueprint style Flask app. Will it still work if I use the `init_app` method? I'm just not sure why when I emit an event on the frontend it is not picked up by the flask backend. And this only happens when I add the message queue. Even the built-in events like `connect` don't fire on the backend.

Comment: Sure, you can use `init_app()` as well.